# Cache custom class

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app I am working with the SimpleKML framework

https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML

I have some big files which takes about 5 seconds to process thought this library. I was thinking to cache the object in something like NSData.

I have read this tutorial from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html

But i dont really know of using nscoder is the best way to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider using NSCache and NSPurgeableData [as described in this paper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/CachingPurgeableMemory/CachingPurgeableMemory.pdf).

Comment: well, I am actually looking for something that I can save somewhere , in file or something. It look likes nscache cant be saved, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

If the object you're saving (and the objects it has as properties, and their properties, etc.) implement the `NSCoding` protocol then it's, as simple as

```
NSData *savedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:someObject];
[savedData writeToFile:pathToSaveFile atomically:YES];
```

to archive the object into an NSData and then save it to disk, and then later

```
NSData *loadedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToSaveFile];
SomeClass *foo = [NSKeyedUnarchiver loadedData]
```

to load the data and unarchive the object from the data.

If not, you'll need to override `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` for the objects in question to make them serialize properly.

Comment: i tried this, and saving the object works. But, it looks like its not saving everything. The length of the Nsdata object is 299 which is very small. And i cant acces methods or properties from the unarchived object. Its not null cuz when I log it I see: <SimpleKML: 0x1c7410>

Comment: I read this and i looks like im doing everything right. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-BAJDBJAI

Comment: The SimpleKML object must not implement the `NSCoding` protocol properly. See my updated answer for what needs to be done. Might be worth forking the project to make the modifications then sending a pull request.